$\mathbb{P}(A|B^C) = \mathbb{P}(A^C|B^C) \implies A \perp B$?
I'm trying to show that knowing $\mathbb{P}(A|B^C) = \mathbb{P}(A^C|B^C)$ implies $A$ is independent of $B$. I'm wondering first of all if it is actually true and, if it is, how can I prove it?
It's easy to see that $\mathbb{P}(A^C \cap B^C) = \mathbb{P}(A \cap B^C) = \mathbb{P}((A \cup B)^C)$, but it's not clear to me where to go from there.
I do know what $\mathbb{P}(A|B^C)$, $\mathbb{P}(A^C|B^C)$, and $\mathbb{P}(B^C)$ are if that's helpful.

Consider a situation in which $A$ is entirely contained in $B^c$.

The implication does not hold in general.
Shuffle a deck of three cards, consisting of a jack, queen, and king, and draw a single card. Let $A$ be the event that you draw a queen, and let $B$ be the event that you draw a jack.

$P(A\mid B^C)=1/2$. Given you did not draw a jack, you are equally likely to draw a king or queen.

$P(A^C \mid B^C)=1/2$, for the same reason.


However, $A$ and $B$ are clearly dependent, as $P(A\cap B)=0$, while $P(A)P(B)=(1/3)^2$.
